# CSS degradation from Javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, noscript, graceful-degradation

I have a typical news ticker set on a website and am trying to degrade it for people not using Javascript (do these people really exist, I wonder?). Anyway, I'm placing inside my `<noscript></noscript>` tags a simple CSS fix-up of it all but something's going wrong.

The jQuery adds the ticker functions to a main div (`.ticker`), and the degraded CSS properly affects all child divs within this main div. However, the main div is not affected by my CSS.

I'm working on Chrome, so I'm using the Dev Console to check the final CSS working on my ticker div and all the CSS I've coded appears to be affecting it--there's nothing crossed out at all. Nonetheless, border, for example, background, etc., isn't there like it should.

What makes this stranger is that this border and this background are CSS elements from the beginning. I mean, even with Java enabled, these are defined by the CSS stylesheet. So I don't know why my degraded CSS is not working, let alone why disabling Java should affect these elements defined by the main CSS stylesheet.

Has anyone come across anything similar? Does anyone know what may be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: noscript content is parsed as plain cdata text if JS is indeed enabled, is your JS-based ticker inside the noscript?

Comment: No, dandavis. the ticker's html is inside `noscript`. Nor is the JS that handles the ticker, nor the original CSS. The only thing inside the `noscript` tags is the CSS that degrades the 'look' of the ticker (but not the function) when Java is disabled. If Java is disabled, the ticker shows as a simple column, displaying all blocks of news items. I can re-design the 'original' look of each block of news; however, I can't do the same for the ticker... because any CSS will be deployed but, at some point, bypassed... or just not shown, as if there was no CSS there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not remove a no-js class from the body tag with JS and have the no JS CSS use a .no-js selector?